# what's the property in the body of Getbearer Token web activity mean?

Tags: oauth, azure-data-factory

Currently, I'm following this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest#use-oauth) to use Oauth to copy data from Rest connector. I applied the suggested temple ,when I configure this web activity, as for the body content, it show I should provide below parameters. I wonder where to get this parameters?

[image]

screenshot2:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are app registration ID and password.
You need to register an app in Azure AD.

Below MSFT docs provides details about the same:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal

Comment: thanks , I already register an app,  is the application ID match with service principal ID like screenshot 2?

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have to create a service principle in the Azure Active directory :

1. First you have to register the App under the blade of AAD > App registrations > New Registrations.
2. Once you register the App you have to then Assign a role under the Subscription Blade> selecting the subscription proceeding with Access Control(IAM)
3. Then you have copy the tenant ID and app ID under the AAD> App registrations> Your App
4. As there are two options for authentication one for uploading certificate and other for New Application Secret: Go with the 2nd one
5. Then you have to set the client secret for the New client. here is the Microsoft Document: [Option 2: Create a new application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#option-2-create-a-new-application-secret)